# ARKit – Converting OBJ or DAE to arobject

Tags: swift, 3d, augmented-reality, arkit

I want to convert a 3D file like `.obj` or `.dae` to the AR resources object with extension `.arobject`.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

**`.arobject`** is a **special map** that you can use in object detection session. It's not a 3D model but rather:

> The description of a real-world object you want ARKit to look for in the physical environment during an AR session (it's an excerpt from **[official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arreferenceobject)**).

You can make `.arobject` file using one of two simple approaches:

- Put images of 3D detected object inside `Assets.xcassets` directory in Xcode.
- Use the following method that writes a binary representation of the object.

  ```
  func export(to url: URL, previewImage: UIImage?) throws
  ```